# Java - simple string issue

Tags: java, string, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string split in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/string-split-in-java)

I have a string:

```
"jack#james#joahn#logan#"
```

I know there is a method of the `String` class that can seperate it on the symbol `#`. So it will return to me

```
"jack" "james" "joahn" "logan"
```

What is the name of this method?

Comment: _split()_ is what you look for. google.com is what you should learn for.

Comment: Here is one suggestion, if you want to find out methods of a class you can browse javadoc for that class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: The whole list of methods inside the String class isn't so long you can't read it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `String.split("#")`.
For example:

```
String s = "jack#james#joahn#logan#";
String parts[] = s.split("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

See the String.split method.  Here is an [example](http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example):